# How do I view the datapoints that are added to a cluster after applying K-Means algorithm?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis, ibm-cloud, k-means

I have implemented k-means algorithm in scala as follows.

```
def clustering(clustnum:Int,iternum:Int,parsedData: RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]): Unit= {
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, clustnum, iternum)

println("The Cluster centers of each column for "+clustnum+" clusters and "+iternum+" iterations are:- ")


clusters.clusterCenters.foreach(println) 

val predictions= clusters.predict(parsedData)

 predictions.collect()

}
```

I know how I can print cluster centers of each cluster but is there a function in scala which prints which rows have been added to which cluster?

The data I am working with contains rows of float values with each row having an ID. It has around 34 columns and around 200 rows. I am working on spark in scala.

I need to be able to see the result. 
As in Id_1 is in cluster 1 or so and so.

Edit : I was able to do this much

```
println(clustnum+" clusters and "+iternum+" iterations ")

val vectorsAndClusterIdx = parsedData.map{ point => 
val prediction = clusters.predict(point) 
(point.toString, prediction) 
} 

vectorsAndClusterIdx.collect().foreach(println)
```

It prints the cluster ID and the row that is added to the cluster

The row is shown as a string and the cluster ID is the printed after

```
([1.0,1998.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,14305.0,39567.0,1998.0,23.499,25.7,27.961,29.04,28.061,26.171,24.44,24.619,24.529,24.497,23.838,22.322,1998.0,0.0,0.007,0.007,96.042,118.634,61.738,216.787,262.074,148.697,216.564,49.515,28.098],4)
([2.0,1998.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,185.0,2514.0,1998.0,23.499,25.7,27.961,29.04,28.061,26.171,24.44,24.619,24.529,24.497,23.838,22.322,1998.0,0.0,0.007,0.007,96.042,118.634,61.738,216.787,262.074,148.697,216.564,49.515,28.098],0)
([3.0,1998.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,27.0,272.0,1998.0,23.499,25.7,27.961,29.04,28.061,26.171,24.44,24.619,24.529,24.497,23.838,22.322,1998.0,0.0,0.007,0.007,96.042,118.634,61.738,216.787,262.074,148.697,216.564,49.515,28.098],0)
```

But is there some way to just print the row ID and cluster ID only?

Would using dataframes help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `predict()` function of `KMeansModel`.

Have a look at the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel

In your code:

```
KMeans.train(parsedData, clustnum, iternum)
```

returns a `KMeansModel` object.

So, you can do this:

```
val predictions = clusters.predict(parsedData)
```

and get a `MapPartitionsRDD` as result.

```
predictions.collect()
```

gives you an `Array` with the cluster index assignments.

Comment: I tried the predict function but it doesn't seem to print anything? I have edited the question to show the output and the complete function that I have. Can you please take a look?

Comment: `predictions.collect()` alone does not output anything ? I will have a closer look at it, for it was working fine. Regarding the output, the 1s and 0s come from this line `predictions.collect()`, right ?

Comment: predictions.collect().foreach(println)    seems to work. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
println(clustnum+" clusters and "+iternum+" iterations ")

val vectorsAndClusterIdx = parsedData.map{ point => 
val prediction = clusters.predict(point) 
(point.toString, prediction) 
} 

vectorsAndClusterIdx.collect().foreach(println)
```

Seems to solve my problem. It prints the cluster ID and the row that is added to the cluster

The row is shown as a string and the cluster ID is the printed after

```
([1.0,1998.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,14305.0,39567.0,1998.0,23.499,25.7,27.961,29.04,28.061,26.171,24.44,24.619,24.529,24.497,23.838,22.322,1998.0,0.0,0.007,0.007,96.042,118.634,61.738,216.787,262.074,148.697,216.564,49.515,28.098],4)
([2.0,1998.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,185.0,2514.0,1998.0,23.499,25.7,27.961,29.04,28.061,26.171,24.44,24.619,24.529,24.497,23.838,22.322,1998.0,0.0,0.007,0.007,96.042,118.634,61.738,216.787,262.074,148.697,216.564,49.515,28.098],0)
([3.0,1998.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,27.0,272.0,1998.0,23.499,25.7,27.961,29.04,28.061,26.171,24.44,24.619,24.529,24.497,23.838,22.322,1998.0,0.0,0.007,0.007,96.042,118.634,61.738,216.787,262.074,148.697,216.564,49.515,28.098],0)
```